# Altium: Traces got a white pattern

Tags: altium

Two traces swapped from looking like all the other traces to getting this white pattern/mesh. I've tried to google it but can't find any results on what it means.
The image below shows the white pattern.

Thank you for your time!

[image]

Comment: These look like collision markers to me. Are there duplicate traces that collide with each other?

Comment: maybe it has to do with the tracks being differential pairs?

Comment: It shouldn't be due to them being differential as  the other 13 differential pairs haven't been getting the same pattern.

I tried to look into collisions but I can't find any.

Comment: Does the meshed tracks have a matching length rule ?

Comment: I finally found it looking through the rules. The signals where uncoupled for a longer distance than the specified rule allowed. Thank you for your time and engagement!